Is Vor- und Nachname plural?
Which of the following versions of the sentence is correct?

Eine Zahl hat so viele Buchstaben wie dein Vor- und Nachname zusammen.

Eine Zahl hat so viele Buchstaben wie deine Vor- und Nachnamen zusammen.


The question is, essentially, whether "Vor- und Nachname" is plural or singular.

The question is not whether Vor- und Nachname is singular or plural (it's plural) but whether the number of the adjective is determined by each indivdual noun or the enumeration.

Not related to the question, but the semantics in your example (eine Zahl hat so viele Buchstaben) seem weird: a number has digits, a word has letters. What do you mean actually?

They are both grammatical.
The first one is what one would normally expect to hear: most people in German-speaking countries, most of the time, only use one first name and one surname, that is what that is referring to.
The second one reminds the listener that people can have more than one first and last name, and emphasizes that they too are within the intended meaning of the sentence.

I thought that Vorname und Nachname are two names (two things), so they must be plural. How is this related to how many first names you have? "A and B" is expected to be plural in either English or German.

@Vosoni native speakers intuitively understand "dein Vor- und Nachname" as "dein Vorname und dein Nachname", implying there is one of each

Maybe the third variant, "deine Vor- und Nachname", would be correct assuming you have one first name, one last name, so two together = plural?

@Vosoni no, that last one is plainly ungrammatical, there may be other languages where you can do things like this, German is not one of them

Yes, I see that this is common usage, but is it grammatically correct? For comparison, if someone stole both wheels on my bike, Vor- und Hinterrad, is that plural?

Thanks for explaining. So if I understood you correctly, replacing "Mein Apfel und mein Buch liegen auf dem Tisch." with "Meine Apfel und Buch liegen auf dem Tisch." would also be unacceptable. (I wonder what you do if you have 10 objects to list that are yours). Then even if one skips the second "mein", the first one relates to the first word only and not to both, right?

@Vosoni yes, "mein Apfel und mein Buch" is grammatical, "meine Apfel …" is not

Mein Vor- und Nachname is a shortened version of Mein Vorname und mein Nachname. Meine Vor- und Nachname would be a shortened version of Meine Vorname und meine Nachname which is obviously incorrect because adjective and noun must match in number.

I understood, thank you.
